# Show out without submission

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a VERY simple BMI calculator but instread of a submission I would a way to find the total values input and show a message(div) in realtime without having to submit?

```
<label>Weight in kg
    <input text="text" name="weight" id="input1">
</label>
<BR>
<label>Height in cm
    <input text="text" name="height" id="input2">
</label>
<BR>
<button type="button" id="button1">Calculate</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(yourBmi) {
    var weight = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    height = height / 100
    var bmi = ((weight) / (height * height));
    var result = ""
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        result= "Underweight";
    } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30) {
        result= "Overweight";
    } else if (bmi > 30) {
        result = "Obese";
    } else {
        result = "Normal";
    }

    bmi = bmi.toFixed(2);

    alert("Your weight is " + weight + "kg" + "\nYour height is " + height + "m" + "\nyour BMI is " + bmi + "\nTherefore you are " + result);
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mudp2bx3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can extract your logic out to a function and call it when the button is clicked, and also when a `keyup` event happens on one of the inputs.

You should also add some (at least basic) validation to check that the BMI value is valid.

> I want the alert to be replaced with a message depending on the value so like a div show hides

In which case you could add a hidden `div` on load which you update the text of and show as needed, like this:

```js
function calculateBMI() {
  var weight = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('input2').value / 100;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');

  var bmi = weight / (height * height);
  var result = "";

  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    result = "Underweight";
  } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30) {
    result = "Overweight";
  } else if (bmi > 30) {
    result = "Obese";
  } else {
    result = "Normal";
  }

  bmi = bmi.toFixed(2);
  
  if (bmi && bmi != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY && !isNaN(bmi)) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Your weight is ' + weight + 'kg<br />Your height is ' + height + 'm<br />your BMI is ' + bmi + '<br />Therefore you are ' + result;
    output.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    output.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.getElementById('input1').addEventListener('keyup', calculateBMI);
document.getElementById('input2').addEventListener('keyup', calculateBMI);
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', calculateBMI);
```

```css
#output { display: none; }
```

```html
<label>Weight in kg
  <input text="text" name="weight" id="input1">
</label><br />
<label>Height in cm
  <input text="text" name="height" id="input2">
</label><br />
<button type="button" id="button1">Calculate</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah man I dont want the alert in there at all. It its terrible!

Comment: the idea is I want the alert to be replaced with a message depending on the value so like a div show hides

Comment: How do i change it from an alert into a simple div? Thats kinda really what i was asking...

Comment: I added an example for you.